# What does the profile text "a laser-like focus on one topic" indicate?

Tags: support, profile-page

As I was looking at the page of a user who had posted an answer, and under the user's *"Top Network Posts"* section I saw this:

[image: Top Network Posts in a user profile]

The bit I'm talking about (in the little red box) reads:

> *"We respect a laser-like focus on one topic."*

What exactly is meant by this?
Does it mean that the user has too many posts that cover a broad range of topics, or does it mean that there aren't any (or enough) posts that cover a single topic?

Comment: Just a funny hint, that the user has no network posts.

Comment: Nicer than saying "Top Network Posts ... None"

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree it is, but why not just omit the *"Top Network Posts"* section if it's empty?

Comment: Because then you'd wonder where it is and what happened.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The user in question hasn't made any posts to any other network site that are [eligible for appearing in the "top network posts" section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254477/145673).  Thus, the system sees them as focused on only one site (or one "topic").

Comment: Lasers only have a laser-like focus when they are... focused. Although when focused they are *really* focused. So it's more like, a focused-laser-focus-like focus. (I hope my point has been sufficiently illuminated. I hope this was spot-on. I hope it is not off-topic. I hope I have been coherent.) (I respect a laser-like monochromaticity on one topic.)